# Update Drawer Navigation using Redux in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

How to update the Drawer Navigation in a react native app based on a boolean in redux store. For example: I want the items in the drawer navigation to change once the user logs in. Is there a way to implement this in react native using redux ( using state is fine too ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two navigation drawer instances. One for not logged in and the other for when the user is logged in and then use accordingly.

Comment: I have my code in this question. It would be great if you could take a look at it.      https://stackoverflow.com/q/53748366/10387115